# Populate is returning empty array

Tags: populate, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to populate the User in Project data

**Model from User
**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    lName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    create_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    let users = this;
    let userObject = users.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    return userObject;
}

module.exports = model('User', UserSchema)
```

**Model from Project
**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./user')

const projectSchema = new Schema({
    user: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    }],
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
    },
    lang: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
    }

}, {
    timestamps: true,
})

module.exports = model('Project', projectSchema)
```

**Controller from Project
**

```
const Project = require('../models/project');
const User = require('../models/user');

const createProject = (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let userIdentity = req.user

    let project = new Project(body);

    project.save()
        .then((projectDB) => {
            if (!projectDB) return res.status(400).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Project already exists'
            })
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                userIdentity,
                project: projectDB
            })
        })

}

const getProjects = (req, res) => {
    Project.find()
        .populate('user', "-\__v")
        .then((projectDB) => {
            if (!projectDB) return res.status(400).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Project not found'
            })
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                projects: projectDB
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'error',
                error: err.message
            })
        })
}

const getOneProject = async (req, res) => {
    let projectId = req.params.id

    await Project.findOne({ _id: projectId })
        .populate('user', "-__v")
        .then((projectDB) => {
            if (!projectDB) return res.status(400).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Project not found'
            })
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                projects: projectDB
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'error',
                error: err.message
            })
        });

}

module.exports = {
    createProject,
    getProjects,
    getOneProject
}
```

Response
[Like i've said. the .populate is returning an empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isqer.png)

I have 4 days trying to solve this problem
i've tried `.populate({path: 'user'})`
with exec or execPopulate

i've tried many solutions and i have the same result

i hope someone could help me

Comment: Can you please share how your project data looks like after saving

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i use populate, You can update 'user' field in your 'Project' schema to:

```js
users: [{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        require: true,
        ref: "User"
    }
}],
```

Then use

```js
populate('users.user')
```